# React-router v3 404 при обновлении страницы

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Подскажите, как настроить react-router v3, чтобы при обновлении страницы он отображал текущий роут, а не 404. Для Dev server неактуально - там есть настройка. Обновление страницы на dev server работает хорошо. Актуально для IIS сервера или apache.

Вот пример моего роутинга
(index.js)

```
<Router
    history={history}
    routes={routes}
    render={applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll())}
/>
```

(routes.js)

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path="password-reset" component={PasswordResetPage} />
    <Route path="password-reset/:token" component={PasswordResetPage} />
    <IndexRedirect to="/quotes" />
    <Route path="profile" component={isAuthenticated(ProfilePage)} />
    <Route path="quotes" component={isAuthenticated(QuotesPage)} />
    <Route path="quotes/:RefNumber" component={isAuthenticated(QuoteLinesPage)} />
    <Route path="schedules" component={isAuthenticated(SchedulesPage)} />
    <Route path="schedule/:scheduleId" component={isAuthenticated(SchedulePage)} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

Comment: ya.ymer большое спасибо за ответ. Все работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.htaccess**
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]`

Comment: Это просто в корне создать надо? где index.html лежит?

Comment: @DennisSpade там, где лежит ваше приложение. в его корне.

Comment: IIS - не работает

Comment: решение для Apache.

Comment: Ясно, а универсального нет?

Comment: универсального, насколько мне известно, нет.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за ответ. Мне все же надо для IIS больше сейчас, так как на нем развернуто приложение и сервисы для тестирования. Apache - это для продакшена уже.

Comment: что-то не работает у меня, создал файл .htaccess, закинул в папку с сайтом (../public_html)  Без него ошибка 404,  с ним - 500(Internal Server Error)

Comment: Все сделал, пришлость конфиг сайта еще редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

Возникла похожая проблема

Решение тут: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing.

1. Создаём файл .htaccess в папке public
2. В нём записываем:

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

3. Запускаем `npm run build`
4. Заливаем на хост.